# auto login to wordpress from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET project with username & password for URL which is a WordPress. How can I create a redirect method in ASP.NET so that it directly logs in to the admin panel of WordPress site?

Comment: "*I seen this before but it does not help me and I don't understand it.*" if you don't understand it, how do you know it's not what you need?

Comment: @James because solution in this post are not cleared. he just answer himself and don't published any code .i want redirect to admin page hi just want something for authentication but i think answer  is close to this link .

Comment: So why mention it? It's confusing. You link to a post as if relevant, then state it's not relevant, but also you don't understand it.

Comment: @James ok i have edit it but do u you have any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

If you do this the easy way you are certain to have your WordPress password stolen by a cybercriminal.

Nevertheless it is worth explaining.

Do `View Source...` on your wordpress admin login page, and look for the form definition in HTML. Stripped of a lot of extra stuff, it will look something like this.

```
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" a
    ction="https://wordpress.example.net/wp-login.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="input" value="" size="20" />
        <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="input" value="" size="20" />
</form>
```

So, you could try a redirect string like this:

```
https://wordpress.example.com/wp-login.php?name=admin&pwd=foobar
```

to use a GET request to provide the username and password. But it does not work: WordPress insists the username and password come in POST request parameters.   Therefore, you need to have your asp.net code write out a minimal web page containing a minimal form and some Javascript to post that form.

That form page will, as written to the web browser, look something like this.

```
<html><head></head><body>
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" 
      action="https://wordpress.example.net/wp-login.php"
      method="post">
        <input type="text" name="log" value="USERNAME" />
        <input type="password" name="pwd" value="PASSWORD" size="20" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('loginform').submit();
</script>
</body></html>
```

See how this works? You create the simplest possible html form with the values (for USERNAME and PASSWORD) included in it. You follow that with the  simplest possible Javascript code to post the form immediately.  When you pass that form to your user's browser, the browser posts it to WordPress immediately, and you get the WordPress control panel in the browser.

**But this is horrible security**:  All that's needed for a cybercriminal to find out your WordPress password is to turn off Javascript, then do View Source on this little web page. Do **not** do this if either your asp.net application or your WordPress instance are accessible from the public internet. If you do, you **will** lose control of your WordPress site, probably within a few hours.

What you actually want is some kind of federated authentication. Active Directory Federation Services, SAML, and OAuth are three ways to do it.All are reasonably secure. All have WordPress plugins. And all require a lot of system administration skills to install and configure.

Comment: tanx for reply i hear you about security risk and research a bit on second part and let you now about the result